# Xpath - Count number of nodes with same value as current node

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I count the number of nodes that have the same value as the current node in XPath 1.0?

For example, if I'm in `Name` Level, value `Name1` should return `2` in my query.

```
<Item1>
  <Name>Name1</Name>
  <Id>123</Id>
</Item1>
<Item2>
  <Name>Name2</Name>
  <Id>124</Id>
</Item2>
<Item3>
  <Name>Name1</Name>
  <Id>125</Id>
</Item3>
```

Comment: Which language are you using? Can you please edit your input to be a proper XML. And please post your try here.

Comment: I don't think there is pure xpath 1.0 solution for this

Comment: count(//*[. = //Item1/Name])

Comment: Are you wanting to count the number of nodes *at the same level* as the current node, and/or *having the same element name* as the current node? (besides having the same text value). Also to elaborate on Lingamurthy's question, what language are you using XPath in... XSLT? Because that could make the difference between an answer being possible and not being possible. (As har07 alluded to.)

Comment: @splash58: That sort of works, but the question was for "same value as the *current node*".

Comment: @LarsH Same level as current node

Comment: I am using a customised tool so I can only use pure XPath 1.0 unfortunately

Comment: If the customized tool doesn't allow anything but XPath 1.0, I'd say that tool isn't flexible enough for this task. In XSLT, you could use `current()`, but not in pure XPath 1.0.

Comment: count(//*[. = //Item1/Name and count(ancestor::*) = count(//Item1/Name/ancestor::*)])

Comment: It is the only `the same level`, i think

Comment: @Dalek: Can you clear up this question: is it really a requirement that the query must count the number of nodes with same value as *the current node*, or would you be satisfied with a query that counts the number of nodes with same value as *a specified node*?

Comment: @LarsH the comparison is against the current node as there's an iteration in place. This comparison will be iterated so it can't be hardcored

Comment: If there's an iteration going on, is it implemented in XPath, or is there something else in the context? Can we modify that loop?

Comment: We can modify the iteration

Comment: So what language is the iteration in? Can you show it to us?

Comment: It only has a field to enter an XPath.For example, //Name

Comment: @Dalek have you try my xpath?